# ListView with one SubItem

Tags: java, android, listview, subitem

I know it's been asked a few times. But somehow every answer is too abstract and just doesn't fit my problem.

Okay, as the question says, I need a list where each item has a subitem. I already have a list of items, but without the subitems. As you can see below, I already have two ArrayLists, the first with the listItems, and the second with the subItems. So it would be optimal to solve this problem with these two.

**What I have:**

```
listView = view.findViewById(R.id.explore_list);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        try {
            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> secondArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Integer i = 0; i < DataManager.data.getJSONObject(DataManager.dataTableDefinition[0]).length(); i++) {
                arrayList.add(DataManager.data.getJSONObject(DataManager.dataTableDefinition[0]).getJSONObject(i.toString()).getString("Name"));
                secondArrayList.add(DataManager.data.getJSONObject(DataManager.dataTableDefinition[0]).getJSONObject(i.toString()).getString("Beschreibung"));
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        } catch (Exception ignored){}
```

**Note:**
`DataManager.data.getJSONObject(DataManager.dataTableDefinition[0]).getJSONObject(i.toString()).getString("Name")` and `DataManager.data.getJSONObject(DataManager.dataTableDefinition[0]).getJSONObject(i.toString()).getString("Beschreibung")`  output a string and are not relevant here. They can therefore be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to create something like this?

It's so simple, and this is my demo project for you: 
https://github.com/hiepxuan2008/basic-recyclerview-android
. Hope it will help your issue a little bit, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Ohh, thank you so much. That's exactly what I needed.   :D

Comment: I'm glad that it helps you, and thank you for choose this as your right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class with properties of your main item and its sub-item, then create the ArrayList with your class instead of string.